# Specify an optional pathname with React router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

So I have this route declared in my `index.js` for the React FE:

```
<Route exact path='/documents/:survey_id' component={protectedRoute(Documents)} />
```

I want to return the same component even if the route is `/documents`. In that case, the component would just render with the first `:survey_id` in the users list. I guess I could just add another route like:

```
<Route exact path='/documents/:survey_id' component={protectedRoute(Documents)} />
<Route exact path='/documents' component={protectedRoute(Documents)} />
```

Kind of repetitive so wonder if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having an additional Route, what you could do is have an **optional path** in your Route path like

```
<Route exact path='/documents(/:survey_id)?' component={protectedRoute(Documents)} />
```

> **NOTE:** React path parameters are provided in a way which
>   [`path-to-regexp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) understands.  So to define a parameter as
>   optional you add a trailing question-mark `?`.

Comment: Downloaded with `npm`, did `import 'path-to-regexp'`, and enclosed the last sections of the URL as suggested. It is rendering the `/documents` fine, but when a `/:survey_id` is provided, it is not rendering the route. I'll keep digging into it.

Comment: Did it work out for you or are you still facing difficulties

Comment: Just getting back to this part of the project and now I do need to get it sorted out. Still having the issue as described in my comment, but looking into it.